# when is it ok not to weight a national database analysis

Tags: survey-sampling, survey-weights

I am running an analysis using a national database that has weights available to produce national estimates. However, I am comparing 2 procedures that are very specific to research hospitals only. Would it still be appropriate to use hospital weights to produce national estimates?